# Run PHP and HTML automatically in every directory folder

Tags: php, photo-gallery

I'm making a photo gallery with folders and subfolders of images. I'd like to not have to put an HTML file in every folder. How can this be done? Here is my PHP:

```
<?php

$directory = "thumbs/";
$files = glob($directory."*");
$photoCount = 0;

buildStage();

function buildStage() {
    global $directory, $files;

    foreach($files as $file) {
        if(is_dir($file)) showFolder($file);
        else showPhotos($directory);    
    }
}

function showPhotos($imagePath) {
    global $photoCount;
    $imageFile = glob($imagePath."/*.*");
    echo '<img src="'.$imageFile[$photoCount].'" id="thumbPic"
            onmouseover="imageOver(this)" 
            onmouseout="imageOut(this)" 
            />'."\n";
    $photoCount++;
}

function showFolder($imagePath) {
    $imageFile = glob($imagePath."/*.*");
    echo '<a href="' .$imagePath. '<img src="'.$imageFile[1].'"  id="folder"
            onmouseover="imageOver(this)" 
            onmouseout="imageOut(this)" 
            onmousedown="imageDown(this)"
            />'."\n";
}

?>
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">
<?php include 'jellybox.php'; ?>
</div>

</body>
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Why would you need an HTML file in every folder?

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to do a photo gallery directory. Here's where I'm at so far. When you click a an image in the "PHP Images", it opens the folder but there isn't an index file so it gives an error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use htaccess to map every file to your php code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dependsOnyourPathes/
RewriteRule ^[images|thumb]/(.+).jpg$  script.php?file=$1.pdf [L,NC,QSA]
```

This shows the old image url in the browser bar, but internally calls your php script.
Im not quite shure what your trying exactly. You could also have a rewrite for
a existing folder and sent that to your script. For a more exact answer we need more informations on where files do live on your server.

Comment: This seems like it could work. Here is what I'm trying to do in context. http://dougburnett.com/gsap-test/.